# SVG path(Raphael.sketchpad.js) not smooth in Chrome, but smooth in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, svg, raphael, mozilla

I have a SVG layer over a image (png in the background). The SVG is is put above the image by z-index and is given "pointer-events:none".

The path drawn on the SVG is done through raphael.sketchpad.js and creates a path (as an example) as:

```
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M337.375,853L337.375,853L275.375,776L280.375,717L370.375,683L418.375,719L433.375,773L431.375,782L430.375,783L428.375,784L428.375,785L428.375,786" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; -webkit-user-select: text;"></path>
```

When I draw a circular path on mozilla a lot of path points(around 20-25) are generated and the curve is smooth. However, when similar path is drawn in Chrome, only around 5-10 path points are generated and the path is not at all smooth.

How can I correct this, so that the path works fine on every browser?

Comment: Please file a bug at http://crbug.com with a complete testcase showing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This problem in chrome can be addressed by using `catmullrom2bezier.js`
It will help in better rendering of the paths that are created.

More details can be found on the following link
https://gist.github.com/njvack/6925609